# How do I call a method when a form is submitted?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My goal is to have the method `onClickLogin` called when I press the submit button in a form. But only the method `initialize` (for `loginPageController`) is called. This code works fine, when every methods is in `app` object, but when I add `loginPageController` script has stopped working properly. How do I fix that?

I have this HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.css" />
        <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- Start of login page -->
        <div data-role="page" id="login-page">

            <!-- Start of page header -->
            <div data-role="header" style="overflow: hidden;">
                <h1>Login</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- /header -->

            <!-- Start of page content -->
            <div role="main" class="ui-content">
                <form id="login-form">
                    <label for="login-username" class="ui-hidden-accessible">User Name</label>
                    <input name="login-username" id="login-username" placeholder="User Name" value="" type="text">

                    <label for="login-password" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Password</label>
                    <input name="login-password" id="login-password" placeholder="Password" value="" type="password">

                    <div class="ui-grid-a">
                        <div class="ui-block-a"></div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b">
                            <button type="submit" name="login-submit" value="login-submit">Login</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->

        </div>
        <!-- /page -->

        <!-- Start of second page -->
        <div data-role="page" id="bar">

            <!-- Start of page content -->
            <div role="main" class="ui-content">
                <p>I'm the second in the source order so I'm hidden when the page
                    loads. I'm just shown if a link that references my id is beeing
                    clicked.</p>
                <p>
                    <a href="#foo">Back to foo</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->

        </div>
        <!-- /page -->

        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I have this JavaScript:

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        console.log("app.initialize");
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        console.log("app.bindEvents");
        $(document).on("pageinit", "#login-page", loginPageController.initialize);
    }
};

var loginPageController = {
    initialize: function() {
        console.log("loginPageController.initialize");
        $("#login-form").on("submit", this.onClickLogin);
    },

    onClickLogin: function() {
        console.log("loginPageController.onClickLogin");
    }
};
```

Comment: <form id="login-form"> has no action

Comment: It doesn't matter. Script works properly when all methods is in `app` object.

Comment: You are right @user3106462, but as I show in my answer, you need to let jQuery and jQuery Mobile initialize themselves fully first. I included a Fiddle for you, showing how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**See this working fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/THWZU/7/

---

### 1: jQuery Mobile needs to initialize itself first.

Your code is not being run in the proper order. It needs to be run *after* jQuery and jQuery Mobile do all their own initialization. You need the entire page to load before you call your initialization.

This is all you need, for pure jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    app.initialize();
});
```

This also works for you, with jQuery Mobile:

```
$( document ).on( "pagebeforeshow", function() {
    app.initialize();
});
```

**Keep these events in mind:** http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/

Especially these:

- http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforecreate/
- http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforeshow/

---

### 2: Bind to the button itself and return `false` after that.

New `loginPageController` code:

```
var loginPageController = {
    initialize: function() {
        console.log("loginPageController.initialize");
        $("[name='login-submit']").on("click", this.onClickLogin);
    },
    onClickLogin: function() {
        console.log("loginPageController.onClickLogin");
        return false
    }
};
```

---

**See this working fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/THWZU/7/

Comment: It works? In my browser I still see that when I click Login button, method `initialize` (for `loginPageController`) is called.